# Rails complex routting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

How can I set a route and an endpoint in my controller such that a GET request to /api/users?phone_number= displays details of the user whose phone number was supplied.

## UsersController

```
def index 
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
end 

def show 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: @user
end
```

## routes.rb

```
  namespace  :api do 
      resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to adjust your routes, just the controller:

```
def index 
   if params[:phone_number]
      @users = User.where(phone_number: params[:phone_number])
   else
      @users = User.all
   end    
   render json: @users
end
```

Comment: when I try this code I don't get the correct result. instead I get this: 
curl http://localhost:3000/api/users?phone_number=2625296931
no matches found: http://localhost:3000/api/users?phone_number=2625296931

Comment: please try `curl "http://localhost:3000/api/users?phone_number=2625296931"` (with quotation marks).

Comment: I got an  empty ([ ]) array instead of this [
   {
      "id":97,
      "name":"Xuan Schiller",
      "phone_number":"1-262-529-6931",
      "created_at":"2018-11-28T20:35:52.169Z",
      "updated_at":"2018-11-28T20:35:52.169Z"
   }
]

Comment: The phone you're trying to query is separated by `-`. You have to send the number the same way is saved in the database on the `phone_number` param: `curl "http://localhost:3000/api/users?phone_number=1-262-529-6931"`.

Comment: Commonly, attributes that are separated by dashes or points are saved in the database without any of it (in your case, it would be saved as 2625296931). This practice should avoid this kind of issue, and also prevent numbers being saved in a wrong way, for example: Imagine **1-262-529-6931** is already saved. For example, If you try to save **1262-529-6931** (intentionally or unintentionally), it'll be saved anyways. Then you'll basically two exact numbers, and one with a invalid number format. If it's saved as 2625296931, you'll ensure a unique phone number without any further problems.